# Hotel cancelled my booking while my Schengen visa application is pending

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, hotels

I am from Turkey and I am currently waiting for a Tourist Schengen Visa so that I can travel to Hungary in August.

Today, I received an email saying that my hotel is no longer available and that I have to cancel my reservation, which I don't want to do to avoid making it look like the hotel booking was fraudulent. I booked through a booking website which specifies that the hotel is required to relocate me in the circumstance that I don't cancel, but I have yet to receive a response from the hotel.

If the hotel relocates me to a different address in the same city before my Schengen Visa application is approved, what should I do and how might this affect my application?

Comment: Try emailing the Ministry Of Foreign Affairs at `taj.konz@mfa.gov.hu` or call +361-458-1000 maybe? This is not trivial. If you want, I can try a phone call, at least I have the advantage of speaking Hungarian.

Comment: @chx thats a good idea, perhaps you can post it as an answer once you get an answer from them

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your quick responses, and your kind offer chx! I apologise for replying so late; I really wasn't expecting anyone to reply. At the moment, I'm still hoping we won't need to change hotel; their request for us to cancel seems very suspicious, so we're contesting it. Thank you again - I'll keep a better eye on this page, and post any updates; especially if I need to call the ministry.

Comment: @Garen what happened with this in the end, could you provide an update